# I want to generate all combinations and permutations of an int array in java, but at a specified starting point

Tags: java, arrays, combinations, permutation

I have looked all over, and a lot of people want to know how to generate all permutations of an int array e.g. `int[] arr = {0, 1, 2}`

But I want to know how to do something a bit more difficult.

I want to generate an `int[]` given a length and a max number.
For example:

```
length = 4
max = 2
```

So this means the method must generate an int[] of length 4, and each element in the array must also be a number from 0-2.

Also, the first time the method is called, it must return `[0,0,0,0]`
The second time, it must return `[1,0,0,0]`
And so on until it reaches `[2,2,2,2]`

Finally, I want to be able to pass it a "starting point" as a parameter. So if I give it 0 as a starting point, it returns `[0,0,0,0]` but if I give it 2 as a starting point it returns `[2,0,0,0]`

I am making a 100x100 pixel image. And I am setting the values for each pixel in an int[]

What I want to do each generate each combination of each pixel, to generate a bunch of random pixels, but I want to do it in a systematic way, instead of just giving each pixel a random value.

Comment: What is your question? What have you tried?

Comment: Thats not possible with a native type. Just create your own class and implement the behavoior.

Comment: Sure it is possible. Just need a few loops.

Comment: If no component (R,G,B or A) has a value larger than 2 every image you generate will look completely black to the human eye.

Comment: I know. I was using lower values to simplify the question. If a proof of concept works for low values it will work for higher values.

Answer (score 1):

In essence, you are looking to generate a 4-digit base-3 integer with a specified value; and you want to represent that integer as an `int[]` with the least-significant-digit first. (For example, `2` is `0002` in base 3, so you want `[2,0,0,0]`.)

That is actually quite straightforward:

```
private final int mLength;
private final int mMax;

private int[] generateArray(int value) {
    final int[] result = new int[mLength];
    for (int i = 0; i < mLength; ++i) {
        result[i] = value % (mMax + 1);
        value /= (mMax + 1);
    }
    return result;
}
```

(I assume you can manage the part where you write a method that tracks the current value, and uses `generateArray` to generate an array for that value, and so on.)

Comment: wow, you got it right just with few code. i try to answer this question, but my code just too messy

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. However what I am actually trying to do is generate a 300x300 image, and I just want to set the value for each pixel in the image via an int[] I changed your code a bit to get it to work for my program but I keep getting the exact same result back even if I change the value, here are the changes that I made:

public static int[] generateArray(int arrayLength, int maxVal, int value){
 final int[] result = new int[arrayLength];
 for (int i = 0; i < arrayLength; ++i) {
 result[i] = value % (maxVal + 1);
 value /= (maxVal + 1);
 }
 return result;}

Comment: @s3t: I'm sorry, but I don't understand your comment. What does it mean to "set the value for each pixel in the image via an int[]"? How does that relate to your original question? What is "the value" in your case?

Comment: @ruakh. Sorry. I may have made the question too generalized. I have edited it to give more information.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class GenerateAllPosibleArrayWithLengthAndMaxValue {

    protected final int min;
    protected final int max;
    protected final int size;

    protected transient List<int[]> result;

    protected GenerateAllPosibleArrayWithLengthAndMaxValue(Builder builder) {
        this.min = builder.min;
        this.max = builder.max;
        this.size = builder.size;
    }

    public List<int[]> generate() {
        prepare();
        generate(newArray(), 0, min);
        return result;
    }

    protected void prepare() {
        this.result = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    protected void generate(int[] array, int index, int value) {
        if(index >= size)
            return;
        for(int v = min ; v <= max ; v++) {
            array[index] = v;
            generate(array, index + 1 , 0);
            if(index == size - 1)
                result.add(newArray(array));
        }
    }

    protected int[] newArray() {
        return newArray(min);
    }

    protected int[] newArray(int value) {
        int[] array = new int[size];
        Arrays.fill(array, value);
        return array;
    }

    protected int[] newArray(int[] array) {
        return Arrays.copyOf(array, array.length);
    }

    public static Builder builder() {
        return new Builder();
    }

    public static class Builder {
        protected int min = 0;
        protected int max = 3;
        protected int size = 5;

        public Builder min(int min) {
            this.min = min;
            return this;
        }
        public Builder max(int max) {
            this.max = max;
            return this;
        }
        public Builder size(int size) {
            this.size = size;
            return this;
        }

        public GenerateAllPosibleArrayWithLengthAndMaxValue build() {
            return new GenerateAllPosibleArrayWithLengthAndMaxValue(this);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        GenerateAllPosibleArrayWithLengthAndMaxValue object = 
                GenerateAllPosibleArrayWithLengthAndMaxValue.builder()
                .min(0)
                .max(1)
                .size(3)
                .build();
        List<int[]> list = object.generate();
        System.err.println("result.size = " + list.size() + "\n");
        System.err.println(Strings.toString(list));
    }

}
```